# Formulário enviando pro banco quando atualizo a página

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá, estou com um problema no meu formulário que é o seguinte.

Eu preencho todos os campos e clico no botão de enviar e funciona tudo certo. Quando eu dou um F5 para atualizar o site, ele reenvia o mesmo cadastro que fiz para o banco novamente. Se continuo dando F5 ele continua enviando os cadastro.

Alguma maneira de fazer com que isso pare, quando der F5 ?

```
if(isset($_POST['enviar']) && $_POST['enviar'] == "send"){
            $sql = mysqli_query($conexao," INSERT INTO Comentarios (Nick, Email, Site, Comentario, Identificacao, Moderacao) VALUES ('$Nick', '$Email', '$Site', '$Comentario', '$Identificacao', '$Moderacao')");
        }
```

Comment: Olá,uma maneira de resolver isso é dando um Header('Location:pagina.php'),voltando pra página,mas não sei se essa é a melhor forma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nada como separar as coisas em arquivos diferentes. Veja essa estrutura:

```
+Projeto
---formulario.php
---salvar_formulario.php
---erro.php
```

No arquivo **formulario.php** está o formulario submetido:

Então quando o formulario acima for submetido, será chamada a página **salvar_formulario.php**, que fará basicamente a operação de salvar os dados enviados pelo formulario no banco, e após salvar redirecionar para algum lugar (a seu criterio). Então fica:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['enviar']) && $_POST['enviar'] == "send"){
    $sql = mysqli_query($conexao," INSERT INTO Comentarios 
    (Nick, Email, Site, Comentario, Identificacao, Moderacao) 
    VALUES ('$Nick', '$Email', '$Site', '$Comentario', 
    '$Identificacao', '$Moderacao')");

    //verifica se foram inseridos registros no banco
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao) > 0){
       header('Location: formulario.php');
    }else{
       header('Location: erro.php');
    }
}
```

Com isso após preencher preencher o formulario você será redireciondo para o arquivo **salvar_formulario.php**, e novamente redirecionado para o arquivo **formulario.php** caso dê certo a inserção, ou para o arquivo erro.php caso aconteça algum erro ao inserir no banco.

Isso é conhecido como [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Outra opção seria você fazer o submit do formulario usando ajax. Usando a [api fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), seu **formulario.php** ficaria assim:

```
<form action="salvar_formulario.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="algum_nome">
    <button id="salvar" name="enviar">Salvar</button>
</form>

<script>

var enviar = document.getElementById('salvar');

//adiciona evento de click no botão salvar
enviar.addEventListener('click', function(){
    enviarForm();
});

function enviarForm(){

//pega os dados do formulario
var form = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
fetch("/salvar_formulario.php", {
  method: "POST",
  body: form
}).then(function(resposta) {
  return response.text();
})
.then(function(resposta) {
  alert(resposta);
});

}

</script>
```

Já o arquivo **salvar_formulario.php** seria alterado para:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
        $sql = mysqli_query($conexao," INSERT INTO Comentarios 
        (Nick, Email, Site, Comentario, Identificacao, Moderacao) 
        VALUES ('$Nick', '$Email', '$Site', '$Comentario', 
        '$Identificacao', '$Moderacao')");

        //verifica se foram inseridos registros no banco
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao) > 0){
           echo 'Salvo com sucesso';
        }else{
           echo 'erro ao salvar';
        }
}
```